# Is there any way to undo a suggested edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

So I was editing a question this morning that had half of its relevant code accidentally commented out.  These kinds of edits are generally quick, easy, and obvious, so it's easy for another editor to beat you to the punch.

I received the dialog box that informed me that another edit had been made; my edit would only be approved if mine was more thorough, etc.  Of course, they were probably performing the same edit, but I didn't double-check on this particular occasion.  I guess my thought was that if our edits were virtually identical, mine wouldn't go through anyway: so I went ahead and submitted the suggested edit.

And our edits *were* virtually identical, with the exception that I maybe added an apostrophe or two, so I got stuck suggesting an absolutely awful edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6946076.

Is there any way to *undo* suggested edits ad-hoc, or is it considered to be simply the editor's responsibility to slow down in these kinds of scenarios?

**TL;DR:** One of my suggested edits was **obviously absolute garbage** that I don't want to waste anyone's time with reviewing. Can I undo it?

Comment: Given how terrible some people's suggested edits are, this one's really not bad.

Comment: I'm also interested in how you can do that, because I suggested an edit that is wrong and it's counter-intuitive that it is wrong.

Comment: One thing to notice is that if you edit that same post again, it will update your suggested edit. So if that happens again, you can try spending more time editing it and even update the edit comment so that you don't get rejected without second thought.

Comment: @user7393973 But if you re-edit it to be back to the original, you’re not allowed to save it because it doesn’t reach the minimum changes limit. So I can’t overwrite my prior edit with a null edit (which makes sense, because I would how up as contributing a 0-change edit and the question would show as being edited recently if that edit were accepted).

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know there is no way to undo your suggested edit.

That being said, an edit that small took me less than 30 seconds to review.  Small edits don't take long review and make sure everything looks good.  I wouldn't worry about it in the future.  If it "wastes time" (and it is a bit subjective as to how small an edit is a time waster vs. being worth it to improve the post) it won't waste much.  Just keep making posts better and let those who can review sort it out.

Comment: It is at least possible to send a new edit on top of the existing one. I'm not sure if it replaces the first edit, or if it adds a second one, but it seems to correctly replace it if it hasn't been already accepted nor rejected.